# How to control a printed double array in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a double array coming from a `JSON` source:

```
// Function and module code omitted ..
$scope.texts = [
  ['Small sheep and ham.'],
  ['Ducks go moo.', 'Helicopters and racecars go bang!']
];
```

I want to output each string in the array as a `<p>` tag.

I tried doing ([example](http://jsbin.com/EzedeTO/1/edit)):

```
<div ng-repeat="text in texts">
  <p ng-repeat="p in text">{{p}}</p>
</div>
```

The above results in all the list being printed,

**BUT**: I want to be able to control which array I am printing through an external controller or directive.

Is there a way of programmatically selecting the array to be printed?

Comment: Your "double array" is in fact an array or arrays. You probably want to use a filter to achieve this.

Comment: @jlareau How can this be achieved?

Comment: Is it the outer div element that is a problem?

Comment: @Emmentaler The problem is that I don't know how to programmatically display only the array item I want. I need to do something like `ng-repeat="text in texts[i]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:
http://jsbin.com/OBoHoSe/1/edit

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
<select ng-model="textidx">
   <option value="0">Level 0</option>
   <option value="1">Level 1</option>
</select>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="text in texts[textidx]">
     <p>{{text}}</p>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

As jlareau already said: This is an Array in an Array. so you have to give an index to the one that should be repeated.

Comment: That's what I mean but how do I print out only `texts[0]` or `texts[1]` using a variable?

Comment: Something like `texts[i]`.

Comment: Where is the variable `i` coming from?  Could you use '{{i}}'?

Comment: @Emmentaler The variable would come from a controller or a model.

Comment: You can also use the ng-repeat style of `text in getTexts()` in which you define a function in the controller `$scope` to filter the results. It is down and dirty but you can refactor it later into a true filter.

Comment: @mainguy [That's](http://jsbin.com/OBoHoSe/1/edit) what I've been looking for! Thanks! BTW, If you could change your answer I will mark is as accept.